# packet reception ration for one hop broadcasting

Tags: omnet++, veins, sumo

Regarding the reliability metrics for VANET safety-critical services , I found that the packet reception ratio for one hop broadcasting =

**PRR(d)= No of Nodes within distance d receiving a packet from tagged node/total No. of nodes within distance d from the tagged node**
then I will compute the average for all vehicles in specific area.

I have a realistic model that build using SUMO, using Randomtrips script to create random trips, so **each second a new vehicle is coming inside the map**.

In omnet++ (veins), to get accurate results, I take only parts from map using Roiroad, also in SUMO I can know the length of each selected edges.

**My question:to compute the equation for each vehicle (X), How can I find the total No. of nodes within distance d from the tagged node(X), in each time the node X broadcast beacon?**

Answer (score 0):

[The tictoc tutorial](https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/tictoc-tutorial/part4.html#s16) explains how to collect statistics. Basically, you add a signal to each vehicle (in the `.ned` and in the C++ code), which you then trigger whenever you want to collect something. That works like this (code is from the tutorial):

```
    //initalization
    arrivalSignal = registerSignal("arrival");

    // in your reception code:
    int hopcount = ttmsg->getHopCount();
    // send a signal
    emit(arrivalSignal, hopcount);
```

Where arrivalSignal is the previously registered signal that tells the statistics tools to do something. In your .ned file, you'll need to map the signal to actually collect something:

```
    @signal[arrival](type="long");
    @statistic[hopCount](title="hop count"; source="arrival"; record=vector,stats; interpolationmode=none);
```

note that the source here is the name you give during initialization; the `@signal` directive tells OMNeT++ what type of data you're recording, the `@statistic` is what is later produced as output.

For your use case, I'd suggest adding statistics collection to your reception code and putting some flag in the beacon that identifies its' source. If you record the ID of the sender instead of the hopcount in the example above, you have a straight-forward way of seeing the amount of packets received per sender per receiver. You can probably extend that to also collect the distance, though I don't see how this is significant if you're talking about packet reception ratios.

Comment: thank you a lot for your useful comment, I already collect the statistics for each node which include **Sentpackets and Recievedpackets**, ..etc.  Based on the equation, I already have the number of nodes that receiving the packets from tagged nodes.   However,  I don not know how can I compute all the nodes that were in the range (either they receive or not receive a packet).  Could you please help me  If there is another way/equation to compute the **probability of beacon delivery **

Comment: I check the traci function in order to count the the total number of active vehicles in the region, I found that **activevehiclecount** parameter give me the total number of active vehicles in all the model while I only need the number of vehicles in specific road (region of interest) ?